# Node modules with sub-directories: "Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'ibm-watson'"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules, ibm-watson

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that calls IBM Watson to get a token. I'm updating it from the old username/password auth to the current IAM auth.

Here's the code from the IBM [documentation](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#authorization):

```js
const watson = require('ibm-watson');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

// to get an IAM Access Token
const authorization = new watson.AuthorizationV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: 'fakekey-1234' }),
});

authorization.getToken(function (err, token) {
  if (!token) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    // Use your token here
  }
});
```

When I run `firebase deploy --only functions` I get this error:

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'ibm-watson'
Require stack:
- /Users/TDK/LanguageTwo/functions/index.js
- /Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v13.10.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js
```

`ibm-watson` is installed in my `/functions/node_modules` directory:

[image]

I reinstalled `ibm-watson`, and for good measure I ran `npm install` in my `functions` directory. Plus I ran `npm-check` and updated all my node modules.

The specific line that causes the error is:

```
const watson = require('ibm-watson');
```

When I comment out that line the functions deploy without error. Unfortunately, the function doesn't run. :-)

This line does not cause the deploy error:

```
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
```

I use IBM Watson in other Firebase Cloud Functions in the same `index.js` file. These lines from other functions don't cause deploy errors:

```
let TextToSpeechV1 = require('ibm-watson/text-to-speech/v1');
...
var LanguageTranslatorV3 = require('ibm-watson/language-translator/v3');
```

The problem seems to be that requiring the parent directory `ibm-watson` fails, but requiring the subdirectories of the parent directory works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as expected. If you take a look at the GitHub repo for `ibm-watson` - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk - you will notice that there is no example requiring the top level library. This stops you from pulling in the full library, when you only need to pull in a small sub-component.